# Mysql Selecting where value in field

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the fields (id, name). The names field is a comma separated array of names. (Ex. bob,joe,tim,fred) I want to select all rows where a value is in that array of names. I have tried where in but cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '$value' IN name
```

Comment: please post your complete relevant code

Comment: @Ejay: I think he did.

Comment: What else is needed to solve this problem? $value is just any name

Comment: See #2 on this page: http://explainextended.com/2010/11/03/10-things-in-mysql-that-wont-work-as-expected/

Comment: Why do you have a comma separated list of names as your value?  Don't do that.  You should only be storing *one* value per field.  Look into something called "normalization".  If you have multiple values, try using another table, and JOIN it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat at least I don't know what he has in `$value`. Nice answer though :)

Comment: Alright i will look into that. Its just that its easier to have it in one line

Comment: @user3574543: Easier how?  In what regard?  As you can see, you are *already* having trouble with it.

Comment: My main table is a list of posts, with user and message and tag. The tag is a list of tagged friends in the post. In the tag field its easier just to have the names with comma separated values

Comment: @user3574543: I'd argue it'd be easier to do it the right way.  It'll save you trouble in the future.  Have a look at: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179103-relational-database-design-normalization/

Answer (score 0):

`IN` only works when you specify each of the elements on your own.

ie

```
'bob' IN ('bob','joe','tim','fred')`
```

MySQL is reading your comma separated string as one value, not as 4.  Your query is being ran as:

```
'bob' IN ('bob,joe,tim,fred')
```

which won't work because `'bob'` doesn't exist in the one element you've gave `IN`.

One solution is to use `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$value', name);
```

This will work, but it will not use indexes.

Comment: This is not working for me, I try echo the num rows and it says mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @user3574543: You need to add error checking.  Don't just assume the query worked.  Get the *actual* MySQLi error and see what it is.  `$result = mysqli_query(...);  if($result === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($con)); }`.  Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

[FIND_IN_SET FUNCTION MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Example: statement finds the search string ‘ank’ at 2nd place within the string list. So it returns 2.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('ank', 'b,ank,of,monk');
```

Function:

```
 SELECT *   
 FROM author   
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(left(aut_name,7), 'William,steven,jung,angalo') > 0;
```

Read the MySQL API and use the example. hope that helps.